# Why to pass function reference instead of method in onClick event of button in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, pass-by-reference

Whenever I pass function parentheses in onClick of button, it automatically calls when page loads even without clicking on button.
But when I don't pass function parentheses in onClick of button, it calls only when button is clicked.

With passing parentheses in function call

```
<button onClick={this.handleButtonClick()}>Increment</button>
```

Without passing parentheses in function call

```
<button onClick={this.handleButtonClick}>Increment</button>
```

Why function called automatically on page load whenever I pass parentheses to function even-though it is written inside onClick of button ?

Comment: you can still do method if you bind it (you can easily achieve it now using arrow binding): `onClick={() => this.handleButtonClick()}`, then it will not calls automatically when page loads

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a difference between a **function call** and a **function**.

When a component renders, all statements are executed and expressions are evaluated. It's plain javascript, that's how javascript works.

`this.handleButtonClick()` is a function **call**, and therefore the function will be called once the component renders. I assume that `handleButtonClick()` returns `undefined` which will cause the button to render as `<Button onClick={undefined} />`. Now, if `onClick` is `undefined`, nothing will happen when the click actually happens as there is no function to be called.

`this.handleButtonClick` is just a **reference** to a function, it doesn't invoke it. You need to pass the function reference to `onClick` prop so that it can be called later by React, once the click actually happens.

Answer (score 1):

It automatically calls because you are invoking it immediately by:

`this.handleButtonClick()`

"onClick" does not work like that, if you want to manually invoke the function you can use:

`onClick={() => this.handleButtonClick()}`

This is done automatically if you use function reference. Hence, you don't need to invoke it or use a callback function. Actually, using function reference is better since that function isn't recreated in every render.

Comment: Using function reference instead of an inline arrow function is better*.

Furthermore, In functional components you should use `useCallback` to prevent the function reference from changing.
In class components, functions should be methods of a class, like the OP has already done.

Comment: @AnteGulin, well, yes. I tried to explain it in my last paragraph with the reason (recreated in every render) :) "...you should use useCallback" Maybe not always? :) https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback

Comment: You can still have a reference to a function that is created in the render method, it's still a reference, but the one that will change in every render too, hence why I commented to clarify further.

Comment: Oh, totally misunderstood. Yes, you are right about that. Using reference doesn't matter in functional components. Since OP uses `this` I explained it as they use class components and thought that you are giving extra information about functional components by saying "should use useCallback" as a general manner.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between function reference and function invoking.

When you set the dynamic value like:
**this.handleButtonClick()**
that means you're invoking the function as soon as the component renders to the page.

But when you just pass the reference of the function like
**this.handleButtonClick**
that means React will call this function only when the user clicks on it.

Answer (score 0):

JS will execute the function On each Render when you do `OnClick(Func(params))`

because you are calling a function instead of passing it.

Do this instead :

```
OnClick ( ()=> {Func(params) } )
```

Comment: I think you missed `}`. Can you check your syntax?

Answer (score 0):

In react functional components, if we pass any function to onclick this way..  `onClick={func()}` this `func` will be called right away when the page is loaded, that for sure we don't want.

So we have two ways to make it work right.

one, pass it as a reference like this- `onClick={()=> func()}` (this means only pass reference to that function when page loads, but call that `func()` if component is clicked over.)

second, just pass the name of the function- `onClick={func}` (this means both pass reference and call on Call).

these both things work the same way. second one is more easy however the former one is used the most.