# Assigning event handler with arguments to events using arrow functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, eventhandler

In the below snippet,during a click event, the arrow function gets called. Now, this arrow function in turn runs the code in its body. Now since `callme()` is a single line statement, so it should return the `callme()` statement (not call it) . But in reality `callme()` is called everytime in the case of the click event.

```
<button onClick={ ()=> callme() } >Click me</button>
function callme() { Console.log("Hi") }
```

This is a confusion that I have. I didnt find any documentation of what should happen in this case. It would be helpful if anyone can share it as well.

Comment: It's in Docs [Handling events - react](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) ...

Comment: @KcH I wanted to know whether the arrow function returns the statement or calls it if the statement has a function invocation in it.

Comment: Here's what it gonna happen -> whenever there is something b/w `{ }` it enters JS land and it gets evaluated, so `onClick={ ()=> callme() }` this gets evaluated during render and it returns the reference to `callme()` function (it doesn't execute the function returned, just returns the function) .... from now whenever you `click` react calls `callme()` and therefore the `log` you see ... hope it helps 

Comment: But it should return whatever ```callme()``` returns. Why is it returning the reference to ```callme()```? AFAIK ```() => callme() ``` is same as ```() => { return callme() }```

Comment: but there is a difference b/w `() => callme()` and just `callme()` .... do you see it now ?

Comment: what is that difference?

Comment: I would suggest to read the [beta docs - cavaets section](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/responding-to-events) ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why to pass function reference instead of method in onClick event of button in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57179063/why-to-pass-function-reference-instead-of-method-in-onclick-event-of-button-in-r)